# Increase or decrease the given time using the interval format P10D and similar

Tags: java, jodatime

How can I increase or decrease the time interval using joda time? 
in php I used to consider DateInterval. But couldn't find the similar approach in java

```
$buildDate = new DateTime(‘2015-10-15’); //"2015-10-15 00:00:00"
$buildDate->add(new DateInterval('P15D')); // "2015-10-30 00:00:00"
$buildDate->add(new DateInterval("P5M")); //"2016-03-30 00:00:00"
$buildDate->add(new DateInterval("P5Y")); //"2021-03-30 00:00:00"
$buildDate->add(new DateInterval("P3W")); //"2021-04-20 00:00:00"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that to do the same as you do in joda time it's better to use [`org.joda.time.DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class using `plus...(int period)` methods as follows:

```
    DateTime today = new DateTime(2015,10,15,0,0);
    System.out.println(today); // 2015-10-15T00:00:00.000+02:00
    DateTime newDate = today.plusDays(15).plusMonths(5).plusYears(5).plusWeeks(3);
    System.out.println(newDate); // 2021-04-20T00:00:00.000+02:00
```

However if you want to use a period notation like you do in PHP you can try with [`DateTime.plus()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plus(org.joda.time.ReadablePeriod)) passing a [`org.joda.time.Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html)`:

```
    DateTime day = new DateTime(2015,10,15,0,0);
    System.out.println(day); // 2015-10-15T00:00:00.000+02:00
    day = day.plus(Period.parse("P15D"));
    System.out.println(day); // 2015-10-30T00:00:00.000+01:00
    day = day.plus(Period.parse("P5M"));
    System.out.println(day); // 2016-03-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
    day = day.plus(Period.parse("P5Y"));
    System.out.println(day); // 2021-03-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
    day = day.plus(Period.parse("P3W"));
    System.out.println(day); // 2021-04-20T00:00:00.000+02:00
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you for helping. But precisely i need to add the periods which are in the format P2D, P3W, etc. The problem is, figuring out should i add days/week/months/year.

Comment: Check my update, where I show how to use the periods in the format you want `:)` : `day.plus(Period.parse("P15D"))...`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Couldnt do directly as you mentioned day = day.plus(Period.parse("P3W"));             Instead considered Period a = Period.parse("P10M");  DateTime added = start.plusDays(a.getDays()).plusMonths(a.getMonths()).plusYears(a.getYears());

Comment: @RohithGowda for the sample I use the last version (2.8.2) check it out  http://www.joda.org/joda-time/installation.html `:)`